# C# Checking if an object can cast to another object fails?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

I'm trying to check if an object can cast to a certain type using `IsAssignableFrom`. However I'm not getting the expected results... **Am i missing something here?**

```
//Works (= casts object)
(SomeDerivedType)factory.GetDerivedObject(); 

//Fails (= returns false)
typeof(SomeDerivedType).IsAssignableFrom(factory.GetDerivedObject().GetType());
```

**EDIT:**

The above example seems wrong and doesn't reflect my problem very well.

I have a `DerivedType` object in code which is cast to `BaseType`:

```
BaseType someObject = Factory.GetItem(); //Actual type is DerivedType
```

I also have a `PropertyType` through reflection:

```
PropertyInfo someProperty = entity.GetType().GetProperties().First()
```

**I would like to check if `someObject` is *assignable to* (castable to) the `PropertyType` of `someProperty`. How can I do this?**

Comment: Can you create a complete program that exhibits the behavior?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen as you have noted in my (now deleted) answer IsAssignableFrom requires a type and not an instance. (MSDN is a bit misleading there) From the code above will be interesting to know if `SomeDerivedType t = factory.GetDerivedObject() as SomeDerivedType;` works or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have

```
 class B { }
 class D : B {}
```

then

```
typeof(B).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(D))   // true
typeof(D).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(B))   // false
```

I think you are trying the 2nd form, it's not totally clear.

The simplest answer might be to test:

```
 (factory.GetDerivedObject() as SomeDerivedType) != null
```

---

After the Edit:

What you want to know is not if someObject is assignable to SomeProperty but if it is *castable*.

The basis would be:

```
bool ok = someProperty.PropertyType.IsInstanceOfType(someObject);
```

But this only handles inheritance.

Comment: But logically, whatever comes out of `GetDerivedObject` must either be `SomeDerivedType` or a descendant, which means that the `true` line of your code would match his last line, which he says returns `false`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Good comments, I might be messing around variables here.. I was just working on a small console app for validation.

Comment: Well, check out http://ideone.com/pRnD2 and you'll see that it *should* work the way you wanted it to, which leads me to think that you have indeed messed up your variables here :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, I would expect `GetDerivedObject()` to return something of the (most common) base class type, ie an ancestor of DerivedType. But we need a more complete question.

Comment: It can't be an ancestor of `DerivedType`, you can't do: `FileStream s = new Stream();` (if we forget for a moment that `Stream` is abstract)

Comment: No, but `FileStream s = (FileStream) factory.GetStream();` might work.

Comment: I'm updated my question to reflect my problem... Am I indeed messing up variables here?

Comment: Thanks for the edit but it still fails... I'm currently attached to the process and in the quickwatch I do the following:

someProperty.PropertyType.IsInstanceOfType(someObject); //returns false

(SomeObjectType)someObject; // works and "returns" someObject casted as SomeObjectType

Comment: Please note that `someObject` is currently casted to `SomeObjectTypeBaseClass`. `someProperty.PropertyType == SomeObjectType`

Comment: I now see that `DerivedType` doesn't actually inherit from `BaseType`. There is however an `implicit operator` defined which I assume is used for casting? Does this complicate the matters a little?

Answer (score 1):

Try use

```
if (factory.GetDerivedObject() is SomeDerivedType)
{
//do
}
```

or

```
var tmp = factory.GetDerivedObject() as SomeDerivedType;
if (tmp != null)
{
//do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I see that your `GetDerivedObject()` is not generic and that you have to cast its result explicitly to `SomeDerivedType`, I'm assuming that `GetDerivedObject` is defined as returning a base type for `SomeDerivedType` (in the extreme case, an `object`).

If so, this line:

```
typeof(SomeDerivedType).IsAssignableFrom(factory.GetDerivedObject().GetType());
```

translates to

```
typeof(SomeDerivedType).IsAssignableFrom(SomeBaseType);
```

which is generally false, as you can't assign a base type to a derived type (you need to cast explicitly, which is what you did).

Comment: In my example the factory method returns a derived type. However in my updated question you can see that the object is actually cast to the basetype. Does this influence the `IsAssignableFrom` method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It might work. It might require some minor changes for it to compile.

```
TypeBuilder b1 = moduleBuilder.DefineType(factory.GetDerivedObject().GetType().Name, TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(SomeDerivedType));

typeof(SomeDerivedType).IsAssignableFrom(b1))
```

Comment: Thanks for thinking along, however I think the problem is related to something else, perhaps me using reflection?